# How to fetch php created json to react native

Tags: php, json, react-native

I've created a table in mysql, for some news data. it comprises of title, body, and link to the image. The file, is saved on example.com/api/news.php, and by following the link will result in an array, something like this:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"News Title 1","body":"Body 1","date":"2020-12-01","image":"Image 1","link":"Link 1"},{"id":"2","title":"Title 2","body":"Body 2","date":"2020-12-17","image":"Image 2","link":"https:\/\/google.com"},{"id":"3","title":"Title 3","body":"Body 3","date":"2020-12-24","image":"Image 3","link":""}]
```

In react native, I tried to fetch by following examples:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://example.com/api/news.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: json.id,
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }else{
      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Content Loaded!</Text>
        </View>
    )
    }
    
  }
```

However, the activity indicator keeps on running. While, when I tried using the original API link from the example which is https://reactnative.dev/movies.json, its working fine. May I know what is the problem that is blocking the json to be read. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: It seems your data is an array and you need to use `json[0].id` to retrieve the value.

Comment: i dont think that is the problem. since I've tried and it still not working. I suppose if the response is successful then the activity indicator should stop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return` from code and maybe you are getting an error in response, try reset `isLoading` state in error like

```
componentDidMount(){
   fetch('https://example.com/api/news.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: json.id,
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      this.setState({ // add this code
        isLoading: false
      })
    });
}
```